# Spring boot: Main class dispatching to different SpringApplication.run classes

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, command-line-interface

I have a Spring Boot application (living in one Maven Project) where I would like to do the following:
Make the main class dispatch to different `SpringApplication` `CommandLineRunners` depending on the first argument, e.g. (Groovy style)

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration

class XxxApplication {
  ...

  main (args) {
    ...      
    switch (args[0]) {
      "merge":
        SpringApplication.run ([Runner1.class, ...], remainingArgs)
        break
      "scan":
        SpringApplication.run ([Runner2.class, ...], remainingArgs)
```

I do not need the full blown Application context for all cases, e.g. some need a database while others work perfectly fine on some local files.

This works, as long as I do not need more complex Beans, e.g., if one of my Runners needs a JPA Repository,

Runner2.groovy:

```
class Runner2 implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
MetaDataRepository metaDataRepo
```

MetaDataRepository.groovy:

```
interface MetaDataRepository extends CrudRepository<MetaData, Long> {}
```

If I run case 2 ("scan") I do get the following exception:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metaDataRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#222681bb' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#222681bb': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:290) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1457) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762) ~[spring-context-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[spring-context-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691) [spring-boot-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar:1.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) [spring-boot-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar:1.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952) [spring-boot-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar:1.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication$run.call(Unknown Source) [spring-boot-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar:1.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45) [groovy-all-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108) [groovy-all-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120) [groovy-all-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
...
```

Comment: Have you looked at Spring's @Profile support as well as profile-specific property files? http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties

Comment: Yes, I am aware of Spring profiles and usually use them to provide different URLs/Users/Passwords etc. to the beans. But I have no idea how I could make use of profiles to make some Beans instantiate or not instantiate. In fact, I was thinking of using different SpringApplications as a shortcut to load different Application Contexts.